# Meaning of 'should have' in sentences

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of 'should have' in the following sentences:

1. I should have let her know what was happening but I forgot.
2. They should have remembered that their guests don't eat meat meat.
3. I should have sent everybody a reminded by email.
4. He should have told them the truth but he didn't.
5. I don't think you should have done it.

I'm confused here because I know that 'should have' is used to imply 'regret'
for example:

1. I got really wet today while going to market. I should have taken an umbrella.
2. She wept so badly. I shouldn't have scolded her.

do the first five examples imply 'regret'? Or, do 'should have' implies both 'obligation and regreats' in all those 5 examples? Or, Do 'should have' implies both 'obligation and regreats' in all those 5 examples?

Comment: I see regret in each of the first 4 examples, please explain what you don't understand.

Comment: do all sentences expresses 'regrets' ? please tell me

Answer (score 3):

You ask whether each of the 5 examples express regret. At first sight, as a native English speaker, it seems obvious that regret is in all 5 examples. This makes me think that we differ in our understanding of "regrets".

I am thinking of **regret** in the sense of "I wish that the situation were different from this; I wish that I had made a different choice or taken a different action."

You give the example:

> I got really wet today while going to market. I should have taken an umbrella.

Here I wish that I had chosen to take an umbrella. You seem to agree that this in an expression of regret. I then don't see any significant difference from that pattern in items 1 and 3:

> 1) I should have let her know what was happening but I forgot.
>   3) I should have sent everybody a reminded by email.

Items 2 and 4 are a little different, in that the wished-for action would have been performed by someone else rather than the speaker:

> 2) They should have remembered that their guests don't eat meat meat.
>   4) He should have told them the truth but he didn't.

But again this does seem to be regret as I understand it, a wish that an action in the past had been different.

Number 5 is slightly different in that we are wishing that an action had **not** been taken.

> 5) I don't think you should have done it.

Note that this could have been expressed as

> I think you should not have done it.

I see regret in both cases, but there's a small difference in feeling between the two: the second is very certain, the first may vary in certainty depending upon how it is spoken. On the written page

> I don't think you should have done it.

implies a "but maybe you were right" on the end. When spoken we might put the emphasis in different places and convey different meaning.

> I **don't** think you should have done it.
>
> I don't **think** you should have done it.

In all 5 cases I see regret, in the sense of "I wish that something in the past were different."

Comment: Please make it clear by editing your answer

Comment: Does 'Should have' imply both obligation and regreat? Please edit answer to make it clear

Answer (score 2):

Besides implying regret for something that was or wasn't done, "should have" can also be used:

1. To talk about past events that did not happen:

> He should have told them the truth but he didn't.

2. To speculate about events that may or may not have happened:

> They should have got the letter this morning. I expect they will let
>   us know about it later.

3. To speculate negatively about what may or may not have happened:

> He shouldn't have left work yet. I'll call him at the office.

4. To tell other people that a different action in the past would have been better:

> You should have helped him instead of just looking on.

5. To talk about something in the past that you ought to or might have done:

> I should have studied more for my test. (If I had, I wouldn't have
>   failed it.)
>
> I should have listened to your advice. (Had I listened to your advice,
>   I wouldn't have gotten into trouble.)

As for the five example sentences, my opinion is that ## 1, 4 may be regarded as both regrets and just statements, depending on the context; # 5 is an opinion about what would have been better; # 3 is a regret, and # 2 is either a reproach for something that wasn't done (also a regret) or a speculation about what may have been done - again, depending on the context.

Comment: Thank you very much for posting answer, in conclusion can we say: All the 5 examples imply the regreats,

Comment: Are the combination of 'regrets and obligation?

Comment: yubraj sharma@ As a reply to your comment a para was added